# Airflow - Change Success/Fail colours (colour-blind)

Tags: user-interface, webserver, airflow

I'm looking to implement Airflow as our task handler but one thing that is realllly bothering me is the default success/running/failed colours in the Web UI.

I'm colour-blind red/green (most common) and it's extremely hard to differentiate at a glance for me to the point I'm thinking about not using it.

Is there a way for me to edit the default colours somewhere? `bootstrap-theme.css` perhaps?

Really really want this to be possible.

Thanks!

Comment: state colors are defined [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/state.py#L65); you can always goto Airflow installation source on your machine and tweak these. But i'm not aware of an elegant way of achieving this. Airflow guys did give us [an anchor point](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L231) to change color of *`task` bubbles* (for each type of `operator`), but changing *state colors* doesn't appear to be that trivial

Comment: Fantastic, that was exactly what I was looking for. One variable applied the change across the whole UI. I manually changed the .css but that didn't work. Happy to accept if you'd like to make it an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

After version 1.10.11, new feature added to customize colors.

From doc

> To change the colors for TaskInstance/DagRun State in the Airflow
> Webserver, perform the following steps:
>
> Create airflow_local_settings.py file and put in on $PYTHONPATH or to
> $AIRFLOW_HOME/config folder. (Airflow adds $AIRFLOW_HOME/config on
> PYTHONPATH when Airflow is initialized)
>
> Add the following contents to airflow_local_settings.py file. Change
> the colors to whatever you would like.
>
> ```
> STATE_COLORS = {
>   "queued": 'darkgray',
>   "running": '#01FF70',
>   "success": '#2ECC40',
>   "failed": 'firebrick',
>   "up_for_retry": 'yellow',
>   "up_for_reschedule": 'turquoise',
>   "upstream_failed": 'orange',
>   "skipped": 'darkorchid',
>   "scheduled": 'tan',
> }
> ```
>
> Restart Airflow Webserver.

See documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/customize-state-colors-ui.html)