# How to customize the Airflow job status colors based on Java job result

Tags: airflow

I'm planning to map the Talend job (or any normal java program) return status code to Airflow Status UI.
Can you explain how to map it?

By default Airflow will show job status in some color like `Success(Green)`, `Failure(Red)` and `up_for_retry(Orange)` based on the job result.

How to show the status based on Java job return code on UI?

Comment: The solution described here might work for you -  https://stackoverflow.com/q/58229238/5848359. You ll have to add a mapping from java-status-code to airflow-task-state.

Comment: Thank you for response....Can you please let me know the clue where to change the mapppings in python.

Comment: **@Ravinder Ryada** as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229238/airflow-change-success-fail-colours-colour-blind#comment102842745_58229238) the mappings are defined [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/state.py#L65). But i don't think it can be changed dynamically (*..based on Java job result..*)